# How, if possible, can you pass in a C# Property to be used like a method?

Tags: c#

I know Func<> is used to pass a method that has a return value to be used inside another method. I know Action<> is used to pass a method that does not have a return value to be used inside another method. Is there a way to pass in a property so it's get/set can be used inside another method?

For example, here is a method that uses Func<>:

```
public bool RangeCheck (int minVal, int maxVal, Func<< int, int >> someMethod)  
{  
    bool retval = true;  
    try  
    {  
        for (int count = min; count <= max; count++)  
        {  
            int hello = someMethod(count);  
        }  
    }  
    catch  
    {  
        retval = false;  
    }  
    return retval;  
}
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
public bool RangeCheck(int min, int max, Prop<< int >> someProperty)  
{  
    bool retval = true;  
    try  
    {  
        for (int count = min; count <= max; count++)  
        {  
            someProperty = count;  
        }  
    }  
    catch  
    {  
        retval = false;  
    }  
    return retval;  
}
```

Is there anything out there like this? I can't find anything. This would be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: You could conceivably do it using reflection, or lambdas, as one of the answers suggests, or a wrapper class. However, using properties this way strikes me as extremely unconventional, to say the least.

Comment: @Mihai, Would one find it unconventional if the parameter itself contains the assignment? It is almost the same as using `out` and readable. `RangeCheck(0, 10, x=> class.Property = x)`

Comment: Well, I kind of take issue with this whole concept of probing an object by throwing values at it and seeing what sticks. Besides, if you want to set a property on an object, why not just pass the object itself as a parameter?

Answer (score 6):

Could you use a lambda as a wrapper?

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

bool val = RangeCheck(0, 10, () => myClass.MyProperty);
```

If you're looking to do both, you would make two lambdas, one for set, and one for get.

```
bool val = RangeCheck(0, 10, () => myClass.MyProperty, (y) => myClass.MyProperty = y);
```

My syntax is probably off, but I think this gives the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of. You could try using reflection and pass the object along with the corresponding PropertyInfo object of the property you want to get the value of. You then call PropertyInfo's SetValue function to assign a value to it (assuming it's read/write, of course).

```
    public void SetMyIntValue()
    {
        SetPropertyValue(this, this.GetType().GetProperty("MyInt"));
    }

    public int MyInt { get; set; }

    public void SetPropertyValue(object obj, PropertyInfo pInfo)
    {
        pInfo.SetValue(obj, 5);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply make it a `ref` argument?

```
public bool RangeCheck(int min, int max, ref int someProperty)
```

You can now set the value of `someProperty` inside the method.

And call it like so:

```
RangeCheck(min, max, ref myProperty);
```

Comment: You cannot use the `ref` or `out` for Properties. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xd8bbw5(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Silvermind True, the caller could not pass `ref instance.Prop`, he would have to use a variable and assign it to the property afterward. Still, I think this answer proposes the most natural method signature.

Comment: @default.kramer I think muratgu should put it inside his answer for clarity ;).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Func` like this `Func<int, T>`

```
void Main()
{
    var sc = new SimpleClass();
    var result = RangeCheck(0, 10, x => sc.Value = x );
    System.Console.WriteLine(result);
    System.Console.WriteLine(sc.Value);
}

public class SimpleClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public bool RangeCheck<T>(int minVal, int maxVal, Func<int, T> someMethod)   
{   
    bool retval = true;   
    try   
    {   
        for (int count = minVal; count <= maxVal; count++)   
        {
            //someMethod(count); //is not a range check,
            //Did you mean
            someMethod(count - minValue);
        }   
    }   
    catch   
    {   
        retval = false;   
    }   
    return retval;   
}
```